# Create table over an existing parquet file in glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

I have parquet file in S3 over which I would like to create a glue table.
I'm using the boto3 python API to do so.
Here is the code :

```
import boto3

c = boto3.client('glue')

c.create_table(DatabaseName='staging', 
               TableInput={
                           'Name': 'test_table', 
                           'StorageDescriptor': {
                               'Location': 's3://staging/tables/test_table/version=2020-03-26',             
                           'OutputFormat':'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat', 
                           'InputFormat': 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'},
                           'PartitionKeys': [{'Name': 'country'}, {'Name': 'city'}], 
                           'TableType': 'EXTERNAL_TABLE'})
```

If we take a look at the Location field we can see the url to the data.
In the folder version=2020-03-26 we have folder like by 'country=country name', and inside every of those folder we have other folders like 'city=city name' that countains the parquet files.

The excution of this code returns:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPHeaders': {'connection': 'keep-alive',
   'content-length': '2',
   'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
   'date': 'Mon, 06 Apr 2020 08:46:58 GMT',
   'x-amzn-requestid': 'ca5e4af0-a2ec-4af0-a2ec-18c308132e21'},
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'RequestId': 'ca5e4af0-a10d-a2ec-a13d-453dfsdfsds',
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

And I can see the table on glue but when I try to query the table on Athena I have the error :

> describe formatted test_table

```
Your query has the following error(s):

FAILED: SemanticException Unable to fetch table test_table. Unable to get table: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Also I just checked on glue, even though the entry of the table is created I have no information returned from the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working directly with Glue API using boto3 is sometimes too verbose and missing a parameter or two can cause a critical error. Before fighting the API details, I recommend you to take a look at [AWS Wrangler](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html).

With a couple of commands, you can read the data into Pandas dataframe and then create a table with your preferred structure:

```
import awswrangler as wr

df = wr.pandas.read_parquet(path='s3://staging/tables/test_table/version=2020-03-26', 
                            columns=['country', 'city', ...], filters=[("c5", "=", 0)])

# Typical Pandas, Numpy or Pyarrow transformation HERE!

wr.pandas.to_parquet(  # Storing the data and metadata to Data Lake
    dataframe=df,
    database='my_database',
    path='s3://production/tables/test_table/version=2020-03-26',
    partition_cols=['country', 'city'],
)
```

If you are using PySpark and want to register the data frame in Glue:

```
import awswrangler as wr

dataframe.write \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .format("parquet") \
        .partitionBy(["country", "city"]) \
        .save(compression="gzip", path="s3://production/tables/test_table/version=2020-03-26.")
sess = wr.Session(spark_session=spark)
sess.spark.create_glue_table(
    dataframe=dataframe,
    file_format="parquet",
    partition_by=["country", "city"],
    path="s3://production/tables/test_table/version=2020-03-26",
    compression="gzip",
    database="my_database")
```

Comment: I looked at aws wrangler and it's very interesting. Actually the dataframe I want to save is a pyspark dataframe, I was using the saveAsTable method from pyspark but I was experiencing some issues the table didn't want to be created, (because in my url path I had a space, something like version=2020-03-26 11:02:45.456789), do you think it would work with awswrangler ?

Comment: @RobertReynolds, I've added the example to use it with PySpark to the answer above